# Difference between scheduleAtFixedRate() and schedule() in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Can anybody explain me What is difference between `scheduleAtFixedRate()` and `schedule()` methods in Timer Class with simple code example.

Comment: This is where the documentation would help, but if you have trouble remembering, the hint is in the name, one runs repeatedly at a fixed rate, and the other runs just once at most.

Answer (score 1):

The `schedule(TimerTask task,long delay,long period)` method is used to schedule the specified task for repeated **fixed-delay execution**, beginning after the specified delay.

The `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,long delay,long period)` method is used to schedule the specified task for **repeated fixed-rate execution**, beginning after the specified delay